# Python Perfect Number

Tags: python, return-value

In this Python Question, I should get False if the the number is not perfect. instead, I'm getting "None". What should I change?

```
def perfect(number):
    sum = 0
    is_perfect = False
    if number < 0:
        return is_perfect
    for i in range(1, number):
        if(number % i == 0):
            sum = sum + i
        if (sum == number):
            is_perfect = True
            return is_perfect
print(perfect(8))
```

Comment: Your `if (sum == number):` code should be after the for loop, not inside it. And then you should return False if the number is not perfect (or just reduce indentation of your `return is_perfect` line).

Comment: Add a default `return False` in the last line of the function

Comment: This isn't your problem, but you shouldn't call a variable `sum`, or any built-in name. Shadowing a built-in name means you won't be able to access the thing you're shadowing, since you can't access it by name anymore.

Comment: some thing try to avoid using reserved words as variables, it would work but can cause you problems, `sum` is a reserved word also you could avoid using a `is_perfect` variable but return `True` or `False` directly is more clear the value in every case. Last of all it's returning nothing because if `number != sum` you have no return.. so add an else.

Comment: You can also just return True/False instead of setting is_perfect to True/False after the 'if (sum == number):' and 'if number < 0:' statements. Then you can remove the is_perfect variable while not changing your Code too much

Comment: @Kumpelinus do you mean `True` ?

Comment: @UlisesBussi You mean builtin function name rather than reserved words. Reserved words are keywords (such as `return` or `def`), and it is syntactically impossible to use them as variable names.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh I just mixed both cases

Comment: @alani yeah sorry sometimes i screw it up with those things... I totally mean built in function  `sum`

Answer (score 1):

You should return `False` at the End otherwise None is getting returned implicitly:

```
def perfect(number):
    ...
    for i in range(1, number):
        ...
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi your problem is that you have no return when you don't match  `if (sum == number):..`

so, the simplest solution is to add  an return False at the end. But also your sum condition is inside the for that's not fine because you can encounter a fake perfect
like 24... so be carefull about that condition

*edit* 0 is not a perfect number so add the condition  to first if

```
def perfect(number):
    sum = 0
    is_perfect = False
    if number <= 0:
        return is_perfect
    for i in range(1, number):
        if(number % i == 0):
            sum = sum + i
    if (sum == number):
        is_perfect = True
        return is_perfect
    return False
```

I would totally reshape your code to make it a litle more clear:

```
def is_perfect(number):
    acum= 0
    if number <= 0:
        return False
    for i in range(1, number):
        if(number % i == 0):
            acum += i
    return (acum == number) #return true if the condition match, False if not

#just to check function 
print([(i,is_perfect(i)) for i in range(1,100) if is_perfect(i)])

#output
[(6, True), (28, True)]
```

Comment: Not completely right because AFAIK 0 is also not a perfect number

Comment: this might not get the same results - OP might stop before the last iteration and return True, yours might add one more i and then return False. No, I didn't check the logic if something like this is actually possible (if there is a case like this), it's just what I've noticed in the code.

Comment: Your Code then is correct for the actual implementation of a perfect number, but the Question was technically just ask about the Problem with returning None.

Comment: the op is talking about a "perfect number" solution so, both I answer the None problem but also help with the other one...